# Autoscroll custom console in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-pde

I am trying to create a console in Eclipse that includes some additional feature on top of the normal `MessageConsole`. To include those extra actions I created a class that extends `TextConsolePage` and I override the `createActions()` method much like the [`IOConsolePage`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.2/org.eclipse.ui/console/3.5.100/org/eclipse/ui/internal/console/IOConsolePage.java).

The setup above works great, however the console that is created does not autoscroll when content is added. I've tried to add autoscrolling ability by adding my own viewer and mimicking [`IOConsoleViewer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.2/org.eclipse.ui/console/3.5.100/org/eclipse/ui/internal/console/IOConsoleViewer.java), but when I do that I get a

`NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jface/text/IDocumentListener`

I have `org.eclipse.text` and `org.eclipse.jface.text` both as require plug-ins in my dependencies, so I am not quite sure why I'd get this error. Anyone know what I can do to get past it?

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` can mean a number of things, show us more of the exception.

Comment: @greg-449 [Dependencies](http://imgur.com/MjPa8F0), [Exception](http://pastebin.com/jDEdnG6M), [Viewer Class](http://pastebin.com/SGS5wQHu)

Comment: @greg-449 I'm developing on one system and using the plugin on another. They both are using Eclipse Luna 4.4.1. It looks as the machine that I am trying to run the plugin on has a slightly different version of jface text `3.9.2` vs `3.9.1`. Would that make a difference, even though the manifest.mf doesn't have required versions on it....

Comment: @greg-449 when I created a feature and update site, as opposed to what I used to be doing (copying to dropins folder) it worked. Guess I need to understand what happens differently this way.

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly `IDocumentListener` is in the `org.eclipse.text` plugin not `org.eclipse.jface.text` as you might expect. Add `org.eclipse.text` to the plugin dependencies.

Comment: I already have it there. I have both added. But if I click the "Find unused dependencies", it will remove `org.eclipse.text`